# Are 'Loosely' related entities joined by string in Ef Core possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The domain model:

We have **People** and a list of **Banned Names** that are forbidden. Both tables are present on the DbContext.

```
    class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Optional
        public BannedName BannedName { get; set; }
    }

    class BannedName
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class GameDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BannedName> BannedNames { get; set; }
    }
```

Not all people have a banned name. Some banned names may not be any person's name.

Example **People**:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill |
| 2 | Rodent |

**Banned Names**:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rodent |
| 2 | Clown |

Is it possible to configure an optional relationship between these two entities, joining on the *Name* field? Example

```
var personWithBannedName = _dbContext.People
    .Include(person => person.BannedName)
    .Single(person => person.Name == "Rodent");
```

Would return a single person with the object graph:

```
{ Id: 2, Name: "Rodent", BannedName: { Id: 1, Name: "Rodent" } }
```

Rationale vs other solutions:

1. Storing a bool, e.g. "IsNameBanned" against the Person will require that property to be kept in-sync with any name changes. The data model expressed in the question contains no state to maintain.
2. Using something like a GroupJoin is no good for domain tests/derived properties on our domain classes, we like to setup our models and tests independent of ef core e.g:

```
    var personWithBannedName = new Person
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Some Banned Name",
        BannedName = new BannedName
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Some Banned Name"
        }
    }
    
    Assert.True(personWithBannedName.IsNameBanned);
```

3. We have lots of unit tests hitting an in-memory SQLite database, so using SQL Server specific things (such as nasty view hacks, which we've considered) we're hoping to avoid.

Have trawled through the ms docs and I can't see any scenarios like this mentioned.

Comment: Navigations are used for building sql, and changes to navigations will generate a foreign key in a migration. But you can edit the migration to remove the foreign key...

Comment: Not well supported though https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15854